# How to change toggle switch with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a toggle-switch with CSS and HTML but I want to be able to toggle/change the toggle switch with javascript.

How do I go about this, you can check out the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a99dkxp1/5/) link

```
<div id="activate" class="toggle-switch" data-ts-color="green">
  <label for="ts4" class="ts-label">Activate Account</label>
  <input id="ts4" type="checkbox" hidden="hidden">
  <label for="ts4" class="ts-helper"></label>
</div>
```

My Javascript: but it does not work

```
if (false) {
    // turn toggle switch off
    $("#ts4").attr("checked", false);
    $('#activate').click();
} else {
    // turn toggle switch off
    $('#ts4').attr("checked", true);
    $('#activate').click();
}
```

I want to be able to toggle the toggle switch programmatically when? I get a value from the database

Comment: You have syntax error in javascript. Brackets for if are not closed.

Comment: works fine for me, check again.

Comment: Unclear of the issue - the fiddle you posted works...

Comment: Only `}` were wrong in that, and you just edited, then there is no error left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1) Syntax in javascript, you didn't close "if" brackets.
2) You didn't check use of jQuery in JSFiddle. It won't work without that. That's working example:

```
if (false) {
  // turn toggle switch off
  $("#ts4").attr("checked", false);
  $('#activate').click();
} else {
  // turn toggle switch ON
  $('#ts4').attr("checked", true);
  $('#activate').click();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a99dkxp1/4/

Comment: It works now with your jsfiddle example and mine now but on my live server its not working.

Comment: Make sure you are including jQuery. You should also run your code in document.ready() to wait until all scripts are loaded. Check console in browser and see what's the error.

Comment: @ElChupacabra small typo - switch ON. Also, as a side note (and I guess this is more of a 'taste' issue) you should ask if (true) for readability. Anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

You should use `prop()` instead of `attr()`, since attr only sets the attribute with the given value without any "intellingence" and `checked` is a marker attribute, which does not need to have a value at all. `prop()` has such "intelligence" implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement will always go the "else" way.

```
if(false) {
     // unreachable code
}else {
}
```

just like

```
if(true) {
}else {
    // unreachable code
}
```

Change it to

```
 if(property == false) {...
```

or even better

```
if(!property) {...
```

or inline the condition and drop the if-else

```
$("#ts4").attr("checked", !property); 
$('#activate').click();
```